# Problema con código do while en JavaScript

Tags: condiciones, while, else

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ejercicio Nota</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
//Empezamos con un do.. while para que nos permita introducir más de una nota
        do {
            var nota = prompt("¿Que nota has sacado?");
//Pide una nota por teclado y la guarda en la variable "nota"
            if(Number(nota) == nota){
//Le decimos que el dato a introducir tiene que ser un número
                if(nota >= 0 && nota <= 10){
//La nota tiene que estar entre 0 y 10
                    if(nota < 3){
                        document.write("Tu calificación es muy deficiente");
                    }
                    else if(nota >= 3 && nota < 5){
                        document.write("Tu calificación es Insuficiente");
                    }
                    else if(nota >= 5 && nota < 6){
                        document.write("Tu calificación es Suficiente");
                    }
                    else if(nota >= 6 && nota < 7){
                        document.write("Tu calificación es Bien");
                    }
                    else if(nota >= 7 && nota < 9){
                        document.write("Tu calificación es Notable");
                    }
                    else if(nota >= 9 && nota < 10){
                        document.write("Tu calificación es Sobresaliente");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    alert("Escribe una nota correcta");
                }
            }
            else {
                if(nota!=Number){
                    alert("Introduce un número válido");
                }
            }  
        } 
        while(nota!=undefined); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hola soy nuevo aquí. Estoy empezando a estudiar JavaScript y tengo un problema con un código sencillo. Se trata de pedir una nota entre 0 y 10 y según la contestación del usuario, presentar una calificación. Si el número no está entre 0 y 10 se pide que se introduzca un número válido y si el usuario no pone ningún número, lo vuelve a solicitar.
El problema es que al hacer el ciclo (antes de incluirlo me funcionaba bien pero sólo preguntaba una vez la nota), pregunta todo el rato, pongas lo que pongas y al cancelar, aparecen todas las notas juntas en pantalla.

Incluyo más abajo el código que tengo.

Espero haberme explicado, gracias de antemano. Un saludo

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ejercicio Nota</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
//Empezamos con un do.. while para que nos permita introducir más de una nota
        do {
            var nota = prompt("¿Que nota has sacado?");
//Pide una nota por teclado y la guarda en la variable "nota"
            if(Number(nota) == nota){
//Le decimos que el dato a introducir tiene que ser un número
                if(nota >= 0 && nota <= 10){
//La nota tiene que estar entre 0 y 10
                    if(nota < 3){
                        document.write("Tu calificación es muy deficiente");
                    }
                    else if(nota >= 3 && nota < 5){
                        document.write("Tu calificación es Insuficiente");
                    }
                    else if(nota >= 5 && nota < 6){
                        document.write("Tu calificación es Suficiente");
                    }
                    else if(nota >= 6 && nota < 7){
                        document.write("Tu calificación es Bien");
                    }
                    else if(nota >= 7 && nota < 9){
                        document.write("Tu calificación es Notable");
                    }
                    else if(nota >= 9 && nota < 10){
                        document.write("Tu calificación es Sobresaliente");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    alert("Escribe una nota correcta");
                }
            }
            else {
                if(nota!=Number){
                    alert("Introduce un número válido");
                }
            }  
        } 
        while(nota!=undefined); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pon en el título _el problema específico_, y reemplaza todas las etiquetas de la pregunta por el lenguaje que estás utilizando. Lee [ask].

Comment: Además, corrige el snippet: ¡colocaste el código html en la sección de js!

Answer (score 0):

Veo algún que otro problema.Por ejemplo, no puedes comparar una variable(nota) con el tipo de una variable(Number). Podrías hacer esa validación de la siguiente manera:

```
If(typeof nota != "Number")
```

Y la validación del while debe ser así también. `while(typeof nota != "undefined")` 
En todo caso la comprobación debería ser, if(nota != '')  para que te saque del bucle una vez no introduzcas nada.
Te adjunto la documentación de mozilla sobre typeof:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Espero haberte ayudado! Un saludo!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta! De momento lo estoy intentando pero no funciona. Si pongo If(typeof nota != "Number")  con el "number" entre comillas lo toma como un string literal y no reconoce si es un número, sino si la variable está definida como "Numero", lo mismo con el "undefined".  En cuanto encuentre la forma correcta, lo pondré aquí. Gracias de nuevo, un saludo.

Comment: Que raro, debería funcionar. Luego lo miro otra vez a ver.

Comment: Si, lo he probado pero me da algún problema el bucle. Aunque ponga un número de 0 a 10 que sería correcto, me vuelve a pedir "¿Qué nota has sacado?" indefinidamente hasta que lo cancelo de manera manual.

Comment: Prueba con while( nota ! = ' ') o while(nota). Te lo va a pedir siempre hasta que introduzcas el prompt vacío. Porque creo que si mandas el promt sin ningún valor la variable se queda así ' '.

Comment: Por cierto, si quieres que cuando introduzcas un valor valido te saque del bucle la validación debería ser:  while(nota <0 || nota >10)

Comment: Pon un break en cada condicional, cuando coincida te pintara el texto y se cortara el bucle. else if(nota >= 5 && nota < 6){
                        document.write("Tu calificación es Suficiente");
                        break;
                    }